# How do I segment data based on response header in siege/ab?

Tags: apachebench, siege

I'm trying to compare two different web server setups behind a common load balancer. They are uniquely identified by the `X-Powered-By` HTTP header in the response.

Is there a way with `ab`, `siege` or similar tool to segment the data so that I can compare my servers side by side?